# Excel source multiple column values to oledb destination single column in ssis 2012

Tags: ssis, bids, ssis-2012

Excel sheet has 4 columns which is filled with data till 500 rows on each column. I want to insert those excel data into single column(PolicyIds) and am using oledb destination. In excel souce i dont hav any column header. Can anyone suggest me how can i do this effectively. (May be i can use script task to get range of data and use it as SQL variable). Is there any best approaches.

Sample excel

A.......B.........C......D

1001     1005       1009        1013

1002     1006       1010        1014

1003     1007       1011        1015

1004     1008       1012        1016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer may work correctly, but i have found some simplified approach.

In excel source select Data access mode as SQL command or SQL command variable(for dynamic query)
Then type below query to unionall all the columns to single column.

```
select F1 from [CA$] where F1 is not null
union all
select F2 from [CA$] where F2 is not null
union all
select F3 from [CA$] where F3 is not null
union all
select F4 from [CA$] where F4 is not null
```

Here my sheet name is CA.If you have column names you can mention your column names instead of F1,F2 etc.,

And Sql command is more faster than default table or view option.

Now i can directly connect to oledb destination without any multicast and sorting etc., Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about best practice, but you can do like this (not going into details as I guess you know):

Let's say you have this tables in database:

```
CREATE TABLE tblFourToOne (PolicyIds INT); --Original, where all your data are

CREATE TABLE tblFourToOne_staging (F1 INT,F2 INT,F3 INT,F4 INT); --temp table to insert data I am using this column names as SSIS gave those as default
```

1. You will recreate or truncate staging table: `TRUNCATE TABLE tblFourToOne_staging`
2. Next you will read data and will insert it into staging table
3. Copy data from staging to original table:

```
INSERT INTO tblFourToOne
SELECT F1
FROM tblFourToOne_staging
UNION ALL
SELECT F2
FROM tblFourToOne_staging
UNION ALL
SELECT F3
FROM tblFourToOne_staging
UNION ALL
SELECT F4
FROM tblFourToOne_staging
```

[image: main control flow]

[image: inner data flow]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there are always 4 columns, and you don't have to detect them dynamically, you could split excel output to 4 pipelines with Multicast, use 4 Sort Transformations (one for every column, renaming them uniformely), and then gather pipelines with Union All. See the screenshots.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Darka Thanks. But it's not fit for bigger volumes, especially with more columns. Script as a source would work much better than multiple sorts.